# How to fix "application: not a procedure;" in DrRacket when trying to use refer to function

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to make tic-tac-toe in scheme and when trying to refer to a variable I get `application: not a procedure;`

```
(display "1 turn")
(define spot (read-line))
(vector-set! row
             (spot)
             1)
(print-gameboard) ; just a display function
```

I expected this to change the vector into `1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0` if I give it one, but I just get `application: not a procedure;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
(vector-set! row
             (spot) ; spot is not a procedure
             1)
```

The variable `spot` is just a value that you read from the REPL; don't surround values with `()`, that's how you call a procedure in Scheme. Just pass it along:

```
(vector-set! row spot 1)
```

But, if you truly intended to make `spot` a procedure, this is how it should be declared:

```
(define (spot) (read-line))
```